# Call services from workflow

Tags: oracle, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am trying to set up a workflow were the content item is either deleted or moved to another folder, if rejected. No wfFunctions seems to be able to do this, only thing related to deleting content is the services, specifically the DELETE_DOC service. But i can't seem to figure out how to call it from the workflow step.

Related question: I have tried to wfUpdateMetaData on the xCollectionID, with no result. Is there a metadata/path i can change to move the file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried <$executeService("DELETE_DOC")$>?

Comment: I have tried, but with no succes. When i do;
<$if wfAction like "REJECT"$>
    <$executeService("DELETE_DOC")$>
<$endif$>
nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to move the item by updating the folder. Note that *wfUpdateMetaData* will only update the latest revision.

Some additional reading:

- https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2015/10/update-folder-during-workflow-webcenter-content/
- https://bitbucket.org/mythics/bypassworkfloweditrestrictions

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tried updating the folder path using <code> <$wfUpdateMetaData(xFolder, "/Contribution Folders/Archive Folder UCM/MYPATH/")$> </code> but with no succes. I would be okay with only updating the latest revision, but is it possible to update a standard field like "folder"?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to update a standard field such as 'folder'. Have you tried updating another field such as 'dDocTitle'?

Comment: I have tried updating the title, with strange results. When i update the dDoctitle nothing happens in UCM, but in the notifikation email the item uses the proper changed name?